# How do I prove that for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2)$?

Tags: induction

How do I prove that for  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$  $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2)$?

I need to use induction.

1. For example if n=1. Than 2=2.
2. If statement holds for  $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$  then follows for $n + 1$

   $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k(k+1)=(n+1)(n+2)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$.

But what I prove with this?

Comment: Your summation signs were all wrong: you didn't give the starting value of $k$. Please note the edits I have made.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the first step, that it is true for $n=1$.  In the second step, you are assuming it is true for $n$ and you want to prove it is true for $n+1$.  So by assumption your $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k(k+1)$ is $\frac{1}{3} n (n+1)(n+2)$, and you want to show that

$$ (n+1)(n+2) + \frac{1}{3} n (n+1)(n+2) = \frac{1}{3}  (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) $$

which is a straightforward calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You have proved the statement via induction. Your job is done.

When you write that $$\sum_\limits{k}^{n+1}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$
What you actually mean is $$\sum_\limits{k}^{n+1}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}(n+1)\{(n+1)+1\}\{(n+2)+1\}$$

So if I represent the mathematical statement $\sum_\limits{k}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2)$ as $P(n)$, then you have shown that **if $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is also true**.

And you have already proven that ***$P(1)$ is true***.

Thus, from the above statement, we have 
Truth of $P(1)$ $\implies$ Truth of $P(2)$ 
Truth of $P(2)$ $\implies$ Truth of $P(3)$ 
Truth of $P(3)$ $\implies$ Truth of $P(4)$ 
Truth of $P(4)$ $\implies$ Truth of $P(5)$ 
$\ldots$ 
$\ldots$ 
Truth of $P(n)$ $\implies$ Truth of $P(n+1)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Hence the mathematical statement $$P(n):\sum_\limits{k}^{n}k(k+1)=\frac{1}{3}n(n+1)(n+2)$$ is true by the principle of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by 2, and you have the fact that the sum up to $n+1$ of 
$  \left( \begin{array}{c} k \\ 2 \end{array} \right)  $ is $  \left( \begin{array}{c} n+2 \\ 3 \end{array} \right)  .$ This is the reason that the total number of gifts given in The Twelve Days of Christmas song is $  \left( \begin{array}{c} 14 \\ 3 \end{array} \right) =364 .$ In Pascal's triangle, this is summing along a diagonal:
$$ 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + \cdots + 66 + 78 = 364   $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have proven that it is true for the case that n = 1 (i.e. that 2 = 2 - this is called the base case). You have then shown that if the relationship is true for n, it is also true for n + 1 (this is the inductive case); this is what the last line shows. Therefore, since it is true for n = 1, it is true for n + 1 = 2; since it is true for n = 2, it is true for n + 1 = 3, ... and hence it is true for all of the natural numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually proved the statement, but it is a little hard to see, because in your inductive step you went from $n$ to $n+1$.  Instead, go from $n-1$ to $n$:

Suppose the statement holds for $n-1$, so
$$
S_{n-1} := \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k (k+1) = {1 \over 3} (n-1) (n) (n+1).
$$
Then
$$
S_{n-1} + n(n+1) =  n (n+1) \left[ 1 + {1 \over 3} (n-1) \right]
=  n (n+1) \left[  {n + 2 \over 3}\right].
$$